# ROS custom message and numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, ros, robotics

I want custom message to contain numpy arrays(I mean creation of .msg file and compiling it).
As tutorial said we have to use `numpy_msg(type)` wrapper to be able to send numpy arrays. But is it possible to include it into my own .msg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message file doesn't change, you still use the ROS-style arrays (e.g., `float32[]`).

The `numpy_msg` wrapper just enables your publisher and subscribers to directly use numpy objects instead of having to do the conversion yourself.

Make sure to watch out for these warnings:

> all of your array data must be initialized as numpy arrays
>
> every numerical array in the Message must be initialized with a numpy array of the correct data type.